# Encrypt text with javascript using server public key

Tags: javascript, java, encryption, cryptography, rsa

I have a Spring Boot application which generate an RSA key pair using `java.security.KeyPairGenerator` and save it in 2 files, Base64 encoded so that keys are readable.
What i'm trying to do is to get the public key with javascript and use it on the client side to encrypt the password field in a login request.

Server will then decrypt the password and check if it's correct.

How can i get server's public key and use it in encryption on client side?

**EDIT** i've said the password but the encrypted content could be any text a user want to send to the server.

**EDIT 2** Using HTTPS or something similar is a better solution and i know it, i'm just asking if it can be done and how

Comment: passwords are not encrypted. They are hashed with good password hashing algorithms like Scrypt, Argon2 with salt and pepper.

Comment: Essential reading for anyone considering client-side encryption with Javascript: https://www.nccgroup.trust/us/about-us/newsroom-and-events/blog/2011/august/javascript-cryptography-considered-harmful/

Comment: I know that, i've only to complete this task it won't be used for production

Comment: if you use HTTPS/TLS/SSL to transmit the password from the web browser to the server then you don't need to do this, i.e. the browser does this and probably better as most browsers have good security teams (and if they don't you've lost anyway, as per @dnault's link)